# Validating an access token with JSON Web Keys in Python

Tags: python, rsa, jwt, jwk

We fetch JSON web key from a customer's server that looks like this (key fields changed):

```
[{'e': 'AQAB',
  'kid': 'vw_aZOVEkZ8TYfJDEewrwruJ2jrrA0',
  'kty': 'RSA',
  'n': 'n_3gWURcfv_dKKbomqqyMEufgqj9Un038_xxxxxx_08nIUaMHCJG8Z8gW-Z3rQP0Iv7gcYv1lol_Asz67tcvDvIksNXWWjkheYbfX_fZ82XKrBbRzDFbYIUa1cwXfM7OodHjlYKLk3ljwMgTHutwvz38E-pNNGP7ZTKmbmOPvM0RPeA_mS-LDDhxq0d3pnUCYRuyzJVZ54SPE2sxxxxxxxxVyZzcPYPBibnNs_v_iiBQsLvwEnMoeTzdJS4D3H2sWS3sh4bnDlhR3950WyCAJugpCeqOlQtx_rBY4EIcH7rZVYkskip200UBoP0q2L61U6XaFTWnKNiFQ',
  'use': 'sig',
  'x5c': ['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'],
  'x5t': 'vw_aZOVEkZ8TYfJDElQuJ2jrrA0'}]
```

In our web application we receive a token like that this that we need to validate against the key above. The token was signed from some external application using the same JSON web key. The access token looks like this:

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6InZ3X2FaT1ZFa1o4VFlmSkRFbFF1SjJqcnJBMCIsImtpZCI6InZ3X2FaT1ZFa1o4VFlmSkRFbFF1SjJqcnJBMCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3N0cy1xcy50dHMtY29tcGFueS5jb20vY29yZSIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vc3RzLXFzLnR0cy1jb21wYW55LmNvbS9jb3JlL3Jlc291cmNlcyIsImV4cCI6MTUwMDAxOTY3OCwibmJmIjoxNTAwMDE2MDc4LCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJjb2EuZ2N4LmRldmVsb3BtZW50LmFub255bW91cyIsInNjb3BlIjoidHRzLmVtYWlsIn0.Q0zzSi7zPfgVQ4E5-eA02eEAFeWZJiREBdeZ6Kep1OSc__P6TEOryJf9MwFU6FWLJeVRjjtsSadEPToh9RAfcBh7SiPCndygYnbQDpvqY3G2V5FjqZdIgEtWMr_RQwE-UKME2bfWZ5blMsRqylBsT0W9UyDOwMdYDFXJ8flTYeFCxb8jBKLc1rxko6uJzf57tN_66IBRpvs10VLGAstRs54Qzn3hYsaZEB3GxENTnQCGGvIyACi0oCaTVatHclH4pr_RDBf5iOOUJkscC4mH4kacWg1_B1q9UrpQ5IOmQtVEk0IIRLDsvHeENaJFHec73j-eeeeeeeeeeee-ytw
```

I looked into the "jose" module for Python

http://python-jose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jwk/index.html

However the example fails with Python 3 (TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly) -> bug report filed.

Are there any other options or modules for validating this token with RSA against a JSON web key?

Comment: do note that the pasted JSON snippet is an array whereas the verification method may require a single key

Comment: Maybe you have a bug in your code. Perhaps showing the buggy code might be more useful.